# Reduce all cases to $x \to 0^{+}$ and $f(x),g(x) \to 0$ before proving L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**[Hypotheses:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)** I. $f$ and g differentiable on $(a,b)$ and continuous on $(a,b]$,
II. $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = 0 \quad  $ or $\pm \infty$
III. $\lim_{x \to a} f'(x)/g'(x)$ exists
IV. $g'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$,

**Result:** $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)/g(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f'(x)/g'(x)$

> **1.** Where do the intervals for continuity and differentiability for $f,g$ emanate from?
> Why not differentiable and continuous on $[a,b]$ too? or why not differentiable on $(a,b]$?
> or why not continuous on $[a,b]$? Or some other possibility?

([http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/notes/lhospital.pdf](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/%7Eholzmann/notes/lhospital.pdf))

[image]

> **2.** For 5 to 7, what sanctions replacing $f$ by $-f$ and similarly for g? Aren't you forbidden to change the hypotheses and the posited $f,g$? You're answering another question?
>
> $6$,7. are more daring. What vindicates the proof to change the quotient too, from $f/g$ to $g/f$?
>
> **3.** How can you presage to reduce all these cases before proving? I didn't think of this trick.

Answer (score 1):

1. De l'Hospital's theorem is rather local in nature. Therefore the two functions should be defined at least in a neighborhood of $a$. Moreover, it is unnecessary to define them at $a$, since we are dealing with limits as $x \to a$. The choice $(a,b]$ is totally equivalent to $(a,b)$.
2. The author means that, **if** you know how to deal with $f \to +\infty$ and $g \to +\infty$, **then**  you can also deal with the case $f \to -\infty$ and $g \to -\infty$. Indeed, $-f$ and $-g$ satisfy all the assumptions of the theorem and $-f \to +\infty$, $-g \to +\infty$. Let me say that I am a bit skeptical about claim 7, and I have always been taught that the case $f \to +\infty$, $g \to +\infty$ cannot be reduced to the case $f \to 0$ and $g \to 0$...

Finally, this theorem is a hard one. You are not supposed to devise a proof by yourself, unless you are a working mathematician.