# Proof of L'Hôpital's Rule for $x \to$ finite $a^{+}$ (J Stewart pp A-46)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Reduce all cases of indeterminate form [to  $x \to 0^{+}$ and $f(x),g(x) \to 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/694863/85079). But Stewart proves it for $x \to finite  \; a^{+}$. I don't know why? Ergo in place of $x \to 0^{+}$, I'll chagrin about $x \to finite  \; a^{+}$ too.

**Modus operandi.** We posit $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{ f'(x) }{ g'(x) } = 0 $.
We want to prove $\lim_{x \to a} \color{deeppink}{ \frac{ f(x) }{ g(x) } } = \lim_{x \to a} \color{deeppink}{ \frac{ f'(x) }{ g'(x) }  } $.
How can we relate $f(x)/g(x)$ and $f'(x)/g'(x)$? The nub is Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem (CMVT).

Hypotheses of CMVT are stronger than those of L'Hôpital`s Rule. They beget:
 There exists $c \in (a,x) \subsetneq (a,b)$ such that $\dfrac{ f(x) - f(a) }{ g(x) - g(a) } = \dfrac{ f'(c) }{ g'(c) } \quad (☺) $.

> **1.** How can you presage to work with $(a,x) \subsetneq (a,b)$ in place of $(a,b)$ ?
>   **2.** And why not work with $(x,b) \subsetneq (a,b)$ ?
>   **3.** Why pick $c \in (a,x)$ ? Why not $c \in (x,b)$ ?

But we want something like $\color{deeppink}{\dfrac{f(x)}{ g(x) } } = \color{deeppink}{ \dfrac{ f'(x) }{ g'(x) } }$. $\lim f(x)$ can $\neq f(x)$, ergo posit $f(a) = g(a) = 0$. Then by the agency of (☺), $\dfrac{f(x) - 0}{ g(x) - 0 }  = \dfrac{ f'(c) }{ g'(c) } \qquad (♫) $

Because $a < c < x$, $\color{red}{if \; x \to a^{+}, then \; c \to a^{+}.}$ Ergo take limit as $x \to a^{+}$ in $(♫)$:

> **4.** Where did this red trick issue arise from? Anything related with Squeeze Theorem?

$\begin{align} \color{seagreen}{\lim_{x \to a^{+}}} \dfrac{f(x) - 0}{ g(x) - 0 } & = \color{seagreen}{\lim_{x \to a^{+}}} \dfrac{ f'(c) }{ g'(c) } 
\\ & =  \color{red}{\lim_{c \to a^{+}}} \dfrac{ f'(c) }{ g'(c) } = \text{ Rewrite c as x } =  \color{red}{\lim_{x \to a^{+}}} \dfrac{ f'(x) }{ g'(x) } \end{align} $.

> **5.** I understand how these last steps behave. But they still feel occult. Please demystify them?

Answer (score 1):

Question 4: The trick is exactly Squeeze Theorem. If $c$ is bounded above by $x$ and below by $a$, $c$ will approach $a^+$ if $x$ does.

Question 5: This change of variables is quite intuitive if you think about it. We seek to understand why this is true:

$ {\lim_{c \to a^{+}}} \dfrac{ f'(c) }{ g'(c) } =  {\lim_{x \to a^{+}}} \dfrac{ f'(x) }{ g'(x) }$.

Think about it like this: $\lim_{x \to a^+} h(x) =\lim_{c \to a^+} h(c)$ for any rational function $h$ - this is simply the tautology $h(a^+)=h(a^+)$. Letting $h(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$, we have shown our statement.

For the first three questions, we can presage to work with the interval $(a,x)$ by looking at the trick we are using: Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem. Knowing this, if we can extrapolate that the two tricks we will be using are setting $f(a)=g(a)=0$ and changing $c$ to $x$, we want to bound $c$ from above with our variable $x$, since we are approaching $a^+$, not $a^-$.

Answer (score 0):

as i remember, the proof of L'Hôpital`s Rule use CMVT

and if we take the limit of the Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem, we will get the L'Hôpital`s Rule immediately!